# Prevent batch file from being closed

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

So, I'm pretty new to writing code. This is actually my first time writing a full batch file.

I am creating a batch file where it will prompt me to choose how long I want the computer to stay on. I plan to put it on my brother and sister's computer for them to automatically stop playing. I know it's silly, but I am just creating it for fun.

This is my current progress.

```
    @ECHO OFF
TITLE Start Restrictions (by Lai Ye Qi)
ECHO DO NOT CLOSE THIS FILE. 
ECHO Please get verification from Ye Qi.
:Start
set /P verif=Please enter verification code:
IF "%verif%"=="0420536" GOTO CorrectVerificationCode
GOTO WrongVerificationCode
:WrongVerificationCode
ECHO Your verification code is wrong, please try again.
GOTO Start
:CorrectVerificationCode
ECHO Correct Code. Proceeding...
set /P UserInput="Ye Qi, how much time are you giving today?"
set /A SelfCalculate="%UserInput%*60"
shutdown -s -t %SelfCalculate%
ECHO Restrictions set successfully. Please ask Ye Qi if you need more time.
PAUSE
```

Is there a way for me to prevent this batch file from being closed by whoever sees this? Also, to irritate my brother and sister, I want to try to make another command where it will reopen useless files/programs when they don't successfully complete this file. Is there any way to do both of those?

Answer (score 0):

Before shutdown command use timeout command to sleep for n seconds then run shutdown command with timeout 0

```
timeout 60
shutdown -s -t 0
```

Comment: So this command is to make it such that if the script does not progress within n seconds, it will shut down? Also, where should I put it in the script?

Comment: this is the replacement of `shutdown -s -t %SelfCalculate%`